# What is the replacement of Microsoft.Web.Services3 in .NET Core that can authenticate with both Username and Signature?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, .net-core, soap

We're currently porting a SOAP client to .NET Core but we're having issues on authentication. Based on our findings, it all boils down to adding both a `UsernameToken` and `Signature` to the SOAP Header. In .NET Framework, we authenticate like so:

```cs
WebServicesClientProtocol client;
X509SecurityToken token;
client.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(new UsernameToken("myusername", "mypassword", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
client.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
client.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(token));
```

We added a WCF Connected Service to our .NET Core project and tried different configurations of the client. The closest we got are something like these:

```cs
// this adds UsernameToken only
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
var client = new MyClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://myservice.com/foo");
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myusername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";

---

// this adds Signature only
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
var client = new MyClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://myservice.com/foo"));
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "mycert");
```

Unfortunately, combining the two does not add both UsernameToken and Signature. We've tried many other variations of the configuration but was not successful.

Our working SOAP request looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action wsu:Id="Id-867b67fc-b2c7-4ca3-bcbb-fdf74ae04baf">http://myservice.com/foo/services/my_request</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="Id-e8c0e394-e80f-453b-b5d6-10369c186b02">urn:uuid:1aad204d-a5f4-4b33-986c-56011dc27ade</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id="Id-790537dd-870a-45e0-9873-427684db6ea1">
      <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To wsu:Id="Id-791bacd6-af9b-4c45-ad13-e7297a8c8ea2">https://myservice.com/foo/services/abcServices</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6a6fb289-7878-413c-b88d-42f0522faa31">
        <wsu:Created>2020-09-29T22:56:15Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2020-09-29T22:57:15Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-2cca8c34-352c-4301-8bb5-da46a8c70746">
        <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>ikb=nqrsp+OH=jEMDl+a1fgC</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2020-09-29T22:56:15Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-7068c9fb-9793-451e-b462-aedf192c57aa">DciPWRsnJhRAOZCeZAwGCV9OzzucIYwvgAVbX46MIQAZNGSgQBcNcEMDDylCc90RdwAV/9XwDB30mJgiV5M8o6ImCggQogABgp0XNTBJnrugnYIGIAj+QUZ0zZivg9Uu/0BxKScQqcGbK43AwEAgwjNPGQ+AXwBAQVMsgFA80OIsQ1IwIwzxGApSzX2A5gY0cVx9rjnMrv+9ctmoqELA91fAgVBcVkATBUTnwQZExrHfxzAwYxAL5jBrngrgK9A2YYDBFDCVrDajRrCdcHM5RQhIwPbBBWMQZTQCAtwuDBsOCkYJKwSbUjvx3Ypg7nTsskyJeP3DPYVtOxpUkEIRYwuisEwANlGMBzmWEbNxMRUQGL2R1/BPFCzXbC/RMMQAVAVlAFB4MwaXYwdopUdMSAzT4F00YswQLf6MMxWDWqlCFwQ98GdHE1K0MnS1weWa+FQ0DVXQVK/JwUukgHvfvplVBPScuWjQAEMMiTSEa94Y5ES5dNdafc5cKIbzbkJCGCsVxxAQl8guEdJQH0cWKC9gROZYqYYFVGjBPkmLi9QgaEpPdBToRtDgTacqty1XyBdhDY3ntJYyxMaAHDeI0KIdKvDBIMCsX2xA8bQ2O8pCdFwQ37GUy1bMfTul7+JQfyyFZknHuVxuiWvNUsoGo0sQn2H3NODdLjMpLgVp3P3MmNc9AuSBzQw3WAGzNR7FnB1fU4VaLzciAAHFiA1LMwbMoIH2FcB907QjFNy08c8BBDoSgdUIp+BxGKyHATeqmHHI7iRsX0BuNv1VuSfnrjAANIWoQNA97DAKnSId5IEG39SaSesXunHQUsCrAMvA9yjcSLjXAxUT7DD2iQgINBLuMmqCz1Y9zUQggC7/I5NUDXO94jAxUg1gVgZZHcbA53SMsA57VwCAUI6AslwA7pGHq2YwbwBTg0Mb+cnEZjA9SuGVeuDnHmVZxgUjWds5snOH+enkMA+BhTzNR7HGNM1AElK0BkfCrgwyqAq22kdc7DnUYGEISIaDm0NYIA1QwBf+J7dwXaBHLmcG7ANAClBXfAQQXAN0g2/zGgFYNKhcgK2HoggNlByd2T0md0Rje00BG9QZlY5DXFNEArT+BPw1TqHYGHEgJhupWG7tsDg/DjANqUVyVEWp4xVjOh9YDIuq8U0TqmD4HVNbbIi2rMTVhZACYoscERM5guBoW4b2u2CCArlFVw1MOELOETnJQKQGNWNaWNVVDjYTsCqMkbqwRU59ijlZIUzhKDFgk098vCDCIwUMhEdA0VYLJvhuNc0QRp9Lakposm9LTKPZAz7yiSF5gwGsjqMACBDwOQMSBEQAaMGN3HNYMFABJQDl1UAbCBZa5gbWwLNdHZhzaawoARcul0Cn6QPQT7BGZGdUcYAlFVMl6k1n3dB70JzcWMapJpZFlI6Bn3IB/RhGDMIQ3D3E/n9wbQZKMDEAbR3VB8WMGZ3lzuHTaUbo2wB5l8Z2I5kt2DsmG7+9DkEYCGCzFA1mGlnIRQmcLBwHJxMRNyPgt0r3XFbIg8+EgzmaFm0M9lbSUVmb5ExAL5++kWxjIzE2oco1kY8sdOtB8OBfQlMyPv9+rEZrz+EDCkxAAIAtkaDRAqwBHpnM7gZmlQObRtgkWhAEbHnQ0Uk9p6geUwqQFAW14vG9Jge/ALNNAdw0AFw0VXmRgCYpLVFFgQoYBWWYH4CBFGidBAAhlDK5/MAjcZMR7S3RRpwvYUNBEorAcNmw1BEv3AjNawWPoI0gANGAHxrAR7Qm6cDIGNoYBLzUCGDfdxASw5gt9wvaN0mPu+JMARO/VfAMd7GY0TGmdDgImtbIKWE6Nnw0bIFi1XCH9AIDHb06Q8ufOxuxM0vz5IBnQLXWyEMQsRiJOBga4Mn0CBhQtciAwQmiqCqxAEj3ywDau2xAEvnEIOoEoxwyWQDHjYrCmSGUUbfM1Pd3WRYgAhTzYwz9fMF3AH0DcapF/IQdILuPBXxIpIGbbgwaCaM+LB4mZo5lBAROlBQrjYiYLjAVBU2zwH70EW49PAoA4GEwEpBIimD4ErDVLDk909BS8QH2y5Bq/BQMYOMIzUvbQkPOjR8EKRA0A+Gkvl8gMRwWYT17RipgAFENrrdSYsYooM5CdQAxs3NJRQLoegJRDcCMKAjjTWC4/AErgoTR1YmDdBBANzcP5ZVFUKOBEA3fvmkBQWnxOjBEjiQzSggLv+m12YsAjx0RdCqwW5VgUw=IAgRGRPVLWBIBVdNP0wWtHBt7esoIOSjDDLAxhftDgMY78oWkxMM8lxRm</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <Reference URI="#Id-157ede06-c0ff-4092-861c-74b7ed541bda">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>GMl851P/=af8OP8gf45n8xsL3fg/</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-ae995838-928a-452e-be22-633ca120855b">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>=VADYKMj8xOqZJZyReClqof3Ve3S</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-583f212c-afe0-4b2a-8f24-94a61ab01c11">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>OUa3ZYsm9=soUTrZ/51ko8YZ1UeX</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-3549607b-958f-4a73-887a-6e25c400368d">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>RCAWZo4o=R3wGfSUZhnA0VSxccEm</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Timestamp-814589a1-8fa8-4d05-bcb5-2cd5e59e4f95">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>nrSGxl2bQ6Ul2Wzgl27nb3ME8=p1</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-c4508205-7502-451a-b57c-ef3bae807828">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>IO5AN6rcQ7gmf+oyZ=YX+hcXamHa</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>wad2UgTSA/1JONW+s1gv/CVHJ85nwuRdakOx57Fpg+jS7R+LWHCAqXljtNS07OdFMHYrrpObgIIs5aSKXJfcdZy/bPuRkQKV=23GUMB3E90c2n42nHFn99ZqMGQJfHpukT71g1exbtlLwQgtCHq903ttBXEB/tkzvfKbQgbR+46gxRCjwlKiDvpUQBngcMOhyf8TZ6dgOWThIMZubJhzd7eXP5rLEl+L4qpOBosFJm6I5HcRSZaF/b/=4JT7U0KmCCLkEaUG+XdGmUyPcdLLGUpOhVh9P74rC7gBxnnyY9+djdu9qu7ibyRjGhngqjNOYu1wNI+Bi5ptK5vjgPwFa15H</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-61f81057-6b05-43c1-9b51-75a9a554f9f0" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-82864924-6cd8-44d4-955d-cd6ed8bf8067">
    <myRequest xmlns="http://myservice.com/foo/params">
      <foo>12345</foo>
      <bar>baz</bar>
    </myRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core does not support the security of the message layer, you can change the security of the message layer to the transport layer or use the .net framework:

[image]

For more information about WCF in core, please refer to this link:

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.1.0.md

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by "change the security of the message layer to the transport layer"? Note that we don't have control over the SOAP service we're accessing.

Comment: WCF has two security modes, one is message and the other is Transport, core does not support message security mode, for more information about it,you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/programming-wcf-security

Comment: If you cannot modify the security mode of the server, you can only use the .net framework, because core does not support the message security mode.